# how to generate table by hibernate for multiple databases in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have a Spring project where for every company registered in the service (CRM system), spring creates a database.

For every new database, Spring must create tables for all entities. I made a multidatabase connection by `AbstractRoutingDatasource` but by using this, the tables in the database are not created automatically. How can I create by Hibernate for a lot of databases?

I expect an example of code in Java.